# how to check if a string in python contains a random set of characters from another string

Tags: python, windows

**i have a source word as a string and i have a string where people input a list of words but how do i check too see of the inputted string only contains characters from the sourceword but in any order**

````
def check(input_string):
    import re
    #http://docs.python.org/library/re.html
    #re.search returns None if no position in the string matches the pattern
    #pattern to search for any character other then . a-z 0-9
    pattern =word
    if re.search(pattern, test_str):
        #Character other then . a-z 0-9 was found
        print('Invalid : %r' % (input_string,))
    else:
        #No character other then . a-z 0-9 was found
        print('Valid   : %r' % (input_string,))```
````

Comment: isn't regex a tad bit too powerful for this simple situation? also please explain where is the string that the user inputs and which one is the source word

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar. It's not too powerful. It's just really unsuited for the task

Answer (score 4):

Use `set`, which supports checking for subset.

```
template = set(word)
if set(input_string) < template:
    print("OK")
```

If you insist on using regex, turn the template into a character class:

```
template = re.compile(f'[{word}]+')
if template.fullmatch(input_string):
    print("OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

def fun():

```
s = "Test" # Word
b = "TEST" #input_string
a = True
for c in b:
    if c.lower() not in s.lower():
        a = False
        break
if (a == False):
    print("Character is not in s")
else:
    print("No Other characters found")
```

Comment: Why define a function if you aren't going to pass anything in?